# Create a Google-Document per Google API Scripting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

i try to create a Google Document per API-Script. For more comfort I want to use more fontsizes and write this script:

```
function myTest() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();
  body.clear();
  text.setFontSize(10).appendText("Line 01\n");
  text.setFontSize(12).appendText("Line 02\n");
  text.setFontSize(13).appendText("Line 03\n");
  text.setFontSize(14).appendText("Line 04\n");
  text.setFontSize(16).appendText("Line 05\n");
  text.setFontSize(18).appendText("Line 06\n");
  text.setFontSize(20).appendText("Line 07\n");
}
```

But it do not work - but why? Does anyone have a sample script for me?

Thanks

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question appropriately

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 2):

- You want to append the text by changing the font size.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? I think that when your script is run, the font size of all appended text will become 20. By using the following script, you can confirm this reason.

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var text = body.editAsText();
body.clear();
var t1 = text.appendText("Line 01\n");
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(t1.getText()))
var t2 = text.appendText("Line 02\n");
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(t2.getText()))
```

`Logger.log(JSON.stringify(t1.getText()))` and `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(t2.getText()))` are `Line 01\n` and `Line 01\nLine 02\n`. This means that in your script, the font size of all texts is changed every time. By this, when your script is run, `setFontSize(20)` which was set at last is reflected to all texts.

In order to avoid this and reflect the font size to each appended text, how about this modification? The flow of the modified script is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Append text.
2. Retrieve the length of text.
3. Set font size to the range of the appended text.

#### Modified script:

```
function myTest() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();
  body.clear();
  var obj = [
    {text: "Line 01\n", font: 10},
    {text: "Line 02\n", font: 12},
    {text: "Line 03\n", font: 13},
    {text: "Line 04\n", font: 14},
    {text: "Line 05\n", font: 16},
    {text: "Line 06\n", font: 18},
    {text: "Line 07\n", font: 20},
  ];
  var offset = 0;
  obj.forEach(function(e) {
    var t = text.appendText(e.text);
    var tLen = t.getText().length;
    t.setFontSize(offset, tLen - 1, e.font);
    offset = tLen;
  });
}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Other pattern:

In your script, you use `\n` to the text. So when the text is appended, the paragraph is increased. You can also use this. But this can be used for only the pattern that the paragraph is increased. So please be careful.

Flow:

1. Append text.
2. Retrieve the appended paragraph.
3. Set font size to the paragraph.

Sample script:

```
function myTest2() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();
  body.clear();
  var obj = [
    {text: "Line 01\n", font: 10},
    {text: "Line 02\n", font: 12},
    {text: "Line 03\n", font: 13},
    {text: "Line 04\n", font: 14},
    {text: "Line 05\n", font: 16},
    {text: "Line 06\n", font: 18},
    {text: "Line 07\n", font: 20},
  ];
  obj.forEach(function(e) {
    text.appendText(e.text);
    var p = body.getParagraphs();
    p[p.length - 2].editAsText().setFontSize(e.font);
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [setFontSize(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, size)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setfontsizestartoffset-endoffsetinclusive-size)
- [getParagraphs()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getparagraphs)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer. Your script is running fine.

I am a beginner so I have change your script in a step-by-step-script:

```
function myTest1() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();
  body.clear();

  var tStart = 0;
  text.appendText("Line 01\n");
  tEnde = body.editAsText().getText().length;
  body.editAsText().setFontSize(tStart, tEnde-1, 33);

  tStart = tEnde;
  text.appendText("Line 02\n");
  tEnde = body.editAsText().getText().length;
  body.editAsText().setFontSize(tStart, tEnde-1, 22);

  tStart = tEnde;
  text.appendText("Line 03\n");
  tEnde = body.editAsText().getText().length;
  body.editAsText().setFontSize(tStart, tEnde-1, 11);
}
```

Currently is the script running about the letterposition. What I search is script like e.g.:

- from now take the FontSize 10
- Write the Text
- from now take the FontStyle "Arial" with FontSize 20
- Write the Text
- from now take the FontSize 33
- Write the Text
- from now take the FontSize 10
- Write the Text
- from now take the FontStyle "Verdana"
- Write the Text
- .......

I hope you now what I mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

now i think i found the way and now i can control the colors, underline, bold,......

```
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var text = body.editAsText();
  body.clear();

  var tStart = 0;
  text.appendText("Check01\n\n");

  tEnde = body.editAsText().getText().length;
  body.editAsText().setFontSize(tStart, tEnde-1, 33);
  body.editAsText().setForegroundColor(tStart, tEnde-1, '#2E2EFE');
  body.editAsText().setBackgroundColor(tStart, tEnde-1, '#00FFFF');

  tStart = tEnde;
  text.appendText("Check01\n");
  tEnde = body.editAsText().getText().length;
  body.editAsText().setFontSize(tStart, tEnde-1, 22);
  body.editAsText().setForegroundColor(tStart, tEnde-1, '#00FFFF');
  body.editAsText().setBackgroundColor(tStart, tEnde-1, '#2E2EFE');
```

How can I take a position in a Line for e.g. only one Line (left, center, right)?

Thanks